# Conversion of python list into table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert data into tabulate form. After installing and importing tabulate module I give following command. Where training_accuracy, test_accuracy and training_step are python list. I am getting the error of invalid syntax. I came across the following command that I want to use

```
`print tabulate([['Alice', 24], ['Bob', 19]], headers=['Name', 'Age'])`
```

But my training lists are quite long I can not type it again and again. How can I fix this error

```
`print tabulate([[training_step],[train_accuracy], [test_accuracy]], 
headers=['Step', 'Train_accuracy', 'Test_accuracy'])`
```

Here is my error
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I tried without passing strings but still getting error of invalid formate

Comment: Then post the code that fails as an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the full error.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python3

Comment: `print` is a function call, so you need to wrap the arguments in `()`. As in `print( tabulate( ... ) )`.

Comment: I hardly installed tabular module Now I want to use that module. Can you please guide me How to convert data into tabular form by this. Or with some for loop

Comment: indeed for python3 the arguments to `print()` need parentheses: `print(tabulate([['Alice', 24], ['Bob', 19]], headers=['Name', 'Age']))` works, see Demo: https://repl.it/repls/FittingAcrobaticExperiment

Comment: As for the syntax error message, the Traceback error should point to the exact location or function that is causing the error (look for the `^` caret) symbol pointing to the location. Similar to how the error looks here, `python2` syntax in `python3`: https://repl.it/repls/UsefulFloweryPolygon

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are encountering at least two problems.

1. You are placing your lists inside square brackets `[]`, which is creating a new list with your list as the first item. Effectively you are making your data 3 dimensional when `tabulate` expects 2D data. You don't need the extra brackets.
2. In Python 3, `print` is a function, so you need to wrap the argument to print in parenthesis

`print(tabulate([training_step, train_accuracy, test_accuracy], headers=['Step', 'Train_accuracy', 'Test_accuracy']))`

Comment: I tried above command but still not getting tabular form. Actually I want to convert data into table that I can esaily copy on Word or latex

Comment: I can't give you any more help if you don't provide a complete example that will reproduce your problem.